How to record audio in React
First, I tried MediaRecorder API to record audio clips but the output files have some issues. Then I tried different libraries such as react-audio-voice-recorder, react-mic, ...etc. But they also gave me the same output.
Issues I face:

The output file doesn't have a length value (therefore audio players don't show the timeline correctly).
Output files are played on Android phones but not on iPhones.

This example of React-Mic-Gold gives the output I want but, it has announced that React-Mic-Gold no longer supporting
I would appreciate anyone with experience implementing an audio recorder in React here.

I fixed the issues mentioned above and created an npm package to simplify usage. If anyone is facing the same issue, please try this out.
react-use-audio-recorder

It looks like you're dealing with an issue I recently encountered while using react-audio-voice-recorder. The problem arises when the recorder returns a Blob URL after capturing the voice note, which you then use in an HTML5 audio tag. The issue occurs because the audio element requires an initial value. If this value isn't set, the audio element might treat it as an indefinite duration, continuously calculating the duration until the audio plays for the first time. After that initial play, everything works as expected.
The solution that worked for me involved using the useRef hook to reference the audio element. I initially set currentTime to Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER to avoid this issue, and then reset it to 0 when the audio starts playing. Here's a sample implementation:


import React, { useState, useRef } from "react";
import { getS3PreSignedUrl } from "Services/NetworkRequestBuilder";
import { FaMicrophone, FaStop, FaTrash } from "react-icons/fa";

const AudioRecorder = () => {
  const [isRecording, setIsRecording] = useState(false);
  const [audioURL, setAudioURL] = useState("");
  const [mediaRecorder, setMediaRecorder] = useState(null);
  const [audioBlob, setAudioBlob] = useState(null);

  const audioRef = useRef();

  const startRecording = async () => {
    setIsRecording(true);
    const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true });
    const recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);

    const chunks = [];

    recorder.ondataavailable = (event) => {
      chunks.push(event.data);
    };

    recorder.onstop = () => {
      const blob = new Blob(chunks, { type: "audio/webm" });
      setAudioBlob(blob);
      const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      setAudioURL(url);
      setIsRecording(false);
    };

    recorder.start();
    setMediaRecorder(recorder);
  };

  const stopRecording = () => {
    if (mediaRecorder && mediaRecorder.state !== "inactive") {
      mediaRecorder.stop();
      mediaRecorder.stream.getTracks().forEach((track) => track.stop());
      setIsRecording(false);
    }
  };

  const deleteAudio = () => {
    setAudioURL("");
    setAudioBlob(null);
  };

  const uploadAudio = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (audioBlob) {
      const file = new File([audioBlob], "recording.webm", { type: "audio/webm" });

      try {
        const { url, fields } = await getS3PreSignedUrl(
          "audio/webm",
          `audio_${Date.now()}`,
          file.name,
          file.type,
          "voice_note"
        );

        // logic to upload
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error uploading audio:", error);
      }
    }
  };

  const handleAudioPlay = () => {
    if (audioRef.current) {
      audioRef.current.currentTime = 0;
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="audio-recorder" style={styles.container}>
      {!isRecording && !audioBlob && (
        <button onClick={startRecording} style={styles.micButton}>
          <FaMicrophone size={24} />
        </button>
      )}
      {isRecording && (
        <div style={styles.controls}>
          <span style={styles.recordingIndicator}></span>
          <span style={styles.timer}>Recording...</span>
          <button onClick={stopRecording} style={styles.stopButton}>
            <FaStop size={20} />
          </button>
        </div>
      )}
      {audioURL && (
        <div style={styles.playback}>
          <audio
            controls
            ref={audioRef}
            src={audioURL}
            style={styles.audioPlayer}
            onPlay={handleAudioPlay}
            onLoadedMetadata={() => (audioRef.current.currentTime = Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER)}
          />
          <button onClick={uploadAudio} style={styles.uploadButton}>
            Upload
          </button>
          <button onClick={deleteAudio} style={styles.deleteButton}>
            <FaTrash size={20} />
          </button>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

const styles = {
  container: {
    // position: "fixed",
    // top: "10px",
    // left: "10px",
  },
  micButton: {
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    border: "none",
    borderRadius: "50%",
    width: "50px",
    height: "50px",
    boxShadow: "0 4px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)",
    display: "flex",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
    cursor: "pointer",
  },
  controls: {
    display: "flex",
    alignItems: "center",
  },
  recordingIndicator: {
    width: "10px",
    height: "10px",
    backgroundColor: "#f00",
    borderRadius: "50%",
    marginRight: "10px",
    animation: "blink 1s infinite",
  },
  timer: {
    marginRight: "10px",
    color: "#333",
  },
  stopButton: {
    backgroundColor: "#f00",
    border: "none",
    borderRadius: "50%",
    width: "40px",
    height: "40px",
    display: "flex",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
    cursor: "pointer",
    color: "#fff",
  },
  playback: {
    marginTop: "20px",
    display: "flex",
    alignItems: "center",
  },
  audioPlayer: {
    marginRight: "10px",
  },
  uploadButton: {
    backgroundColor: "#4CAF50",
    color: "#fff",
    border: "none",
    borderRadius: "5px",
    padding: "5px 10px",
    cursor: "pointer",
    marginRight: "10px",
  },
  deleteButton: {
    backgroundColor: "#FF4D4F",
    color: "#fff",
    border: "none",
    borderRadius: "5px",
    padding: "5px 10px",
    cursor: "pointer",
  },
};

export default AudioRecorder;



Hope this helps!

Could you please add an example in any playground. btw, what is the implementation of getS3PreSignedUrl ?.

Sorry for delayed response. the implementation is simple:


import axios from 'axios';

export const getS3PreSignedUrl = async (fileType, fileName, mimeType, folder) => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.post("/api/generate-presigned-url", {
      fileType,
      fileName,
      mimeType,
      folder,
    });

    return response.data; 
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error generating S3 presigned URL:", error);
    throw error;
  }
};



About the audio recorder component, just use it in a raw react-app and it will work.

didn't you face the issue I faced?
